# Performance of fmt.Scanf() in golang

Tags: performance, go

I am trying to implement my python code in go. Here is a python code to find the inverse factorial of a large digit.

```
def largeInverseFactorial(n):
    len_n = len(n)
    i = 1
    ans = 1
    while True:
        ans += math.log10(i)
        if ans >= len_n:
            return i
        i += 1
```

Here is the go code after translating:

```
func largeInverseFactorial(n string) int64 {
    len_n := float64(len(n))
    var i float64 = 1
    var ans float64 = 1
    for true {
        ans += math.Log10(i)
        if ans >= len_n {
            return int64(i)
        }
        i += 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

I need this go code to work with string of digits where its length can go up to 10^6. But to my surprise the go code is more than 20 times slower than its python counterpart. Can anybody tell me what am I missing in go or what's the reason behind it.

**Update**: The problem seems on the other side. So after using `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')` the code worked well and there is no wrong in for loop which was my original thought. Here is the code it worked:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func smallInverseFactorial(value string) int64 {
    var pre, ans int64
    pre = 1
    ans = 1
    intVal, _ := strconv.ParseInt(value, 10, 64)
    if intVal == 1 {
        return 1
    }
    for ans < intVal {
        ans *= pre
        pre += 1
    }
    return pre - 1
}

func largeInverseFactorial(n string) int64 {
    len_n := float64(len(n))
    var i float64 = 1
    var ans float64 = 1
    for {
        ans += math.Log10(i)
        if ans >= len_n {
            return int64(i)
        }
        i += 1
    }
    return 0
}

func main() {
    var value string
    value, _ = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
    value = strings.Split(value, "\n")[0]
    // fmt.Scanf("%s", &value)
    if len(value) < 3 {
        fmt.Println(smallInverseFactorial(value))
    } else {
        fmt.Println(largeInverseFactorial(value))
    }
}
```

So my question why using `fmt.Scanf()` is super slow when input gets larger?

Comment: " the [Go] code is more than 20 times slower". How do you know? How did you measure?

Comment: Yes I measured it. For a very large number python code can do it in 0.33 second where as go code take about 7.6 second. I am sure something is wrong my my go code.

Comment: Here is the full code https://gist.github.com/uprety/28f618cf04f2ced64c15c02249df14a4 for it. I am trying to solve this https://open.kattis.com/problems/inversefactorial problem.

Comment: "Yes I measured it." How?

Comment: i ran an unit test for your function with the input you gave in the gist, and it only took 0.036s on my laptop

Comment: How **exactly** did you measure how long the Go version takes? Please don’t answer like „I ran an unit test“ but show the actual measurement setup and commands. (Hint your measurement is broken, not Go is slow.)

Comment: Maybe don't use `fmt.Scanf` for large inputs: https://imgur.com/04xaDTv (Go's fmt.Scanf takes 1.3s to read from stdin while Python's input() takes only 1.7ms).

Comment: You can use `value, _ = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')` instead of `fmt.Scanf`. https://imgur.com/a/VBC5JDB

Comment: Solved! Okey, the problem seem to be on reading large input using `fmt.Scanf`. So replacing it with `bufio.NewReader()` did work for me. Thanks @mkopriva any everyone who showed interest in it.